# There is no variable named 'substring'

Tags: mule, dataweave

i want to Change the time "2017-08-22T17:10:12Z" into "20170822".

So i used this substring function but its throw errors continuously.

```
%dw 0.1
%output application/xml
---
po: {
    var:payload.po.ordered_date,
    Date: substring(var,2,3)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function called substring in Dataweave instead use as given below.

%dw 0.1

### %output application/xml

po: {
    var:payload.po.ordered_date,
    Date: substring(2..3)
}

Or you can define a Java function substring in global xml config file and use it as you have given above.

Answer (score 0):

Variable declaration has syntax error. Also in dataweave substring doesnt work as mentioned. Please refer following code

```
%dw 0.1
%output application/xml
%var variable = payload.po.ordered_date
---
po: { 
    Date: variable as :localdatetime as :string {format:"yyyyMMdd"}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How i write the    ----->   " Qty: payload.invoice.lines.*line.quantity,   BIG07:"CR" when Qty*1<0 " in %output application/java

Answer (score 0):

I use Groovy Script to retrieve the substring. Try like below.

```
def testString = 'ABC';
flowVars['subStringedString']=  flowVars.testString.substring(0,2);
```

The above will give you AB.

You can access this substring as `flowVars['subStringedString']` in Mule flow

Answer (score 0):

There is no substring operator in Dataweave and the way you to do this is like var[1..3] is you want get 4 characters from  2nd position. Should be something on lines below

```
%dw 0.1
%output application/xml
---
po: {
    var:payload.po.ordered_date,
    Date: var[1..3]
}
```